# Insert text behind the text in css3

Tags: css

I would like to put a text behind other text, so that the text in the background is larger than the front text. See the below image to understand what I would like to create. Any help or instructions on how to create this are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please add your code and what you tried so far

Comment: you can use `background-image` instead use text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pseudo-elments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and style with css

```css
p:after{
    content: "hotel hotel hotel";
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top:2px;
    color: red;
    width:200px;
    background-color:black;
   opacity:0.5;
   font-size: 48px;
   z-index: -1;
}
p{
color:blue;
width:170px;
   font-size: 28px;

}
```

```html
<p>The hoel resturant and bar</p>
```